# Google app script - attach/embed document into email

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a good way to embed a Google Document into an email?

I can start with:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openById('1P_KZr_xpg.....xntBqvQ');
```

I've tried these approaches:

A) `MailApp.sendEmail('john@abc.com', doc.getName(), doc.getText());`
The raw text from the document forms the body of the email... all formatting is lost.

B) `MailApp.sendEmail('john@abc.com', doc.getName(), doc.getUrl());` The URL to the document is the body of the message. The content of the document is not seen until you click through to the source document.

C) `MailApp.sendEmail('john@abc.com', doc.getName(), '', { htmlBody: HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(doc.getAs('blob') });` This seems promising, but gives an error: "Unsupported conversion requested."

Is there any other way to embed a document?

Is there any way to get the HTML version of a document?  Once I have that, I can use `htmlBody` to insert it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has already been answered a few times, here is the code [originally suggested](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/apps-script/convert$20html/apps-script/gjEVtRd-kIo/rrRPCq4hRAQJ) by Henrique Abreu  (don't care about comments saying it doesn't work, it does !):

```
function emailDocTest() {
  var id = 'Doc-Very-Long-ID-Here';
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
  var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/documents/Export?exportFormat=html&format=html&id='+id,
                              googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getContentText();
  var emailAdress = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAdress, 'test doc send by mail as html', 'html only', {htmlBody:doc});
}

function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

Please note that the googleOAuth_ function need a special authorization that can only be activated using the script editor to run the function (not from a UiApp  or from a menu) and that this function doesn't appear in the 'run' list because of the underscore at the end of its name (this is how it is intended to work) so run it at least once from the script editor and remember that if/when you eventually share the app with someone else. See [feature request 677](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=677) for details.

Comment: It's really too bad that this is the only option.  I have the doc already, so it is strange that I have to get it again.  The API has  getAs(contentType), but doesn't say what is allowed as a "contentType".

Comment: What do you mean?  How /why is that a problem?

Comment: The API has getAs(contentType) only takes "application/pdf" for now.

Comment: I already have the "doc" variable with the Document. I can edit and modify the contents of the file. I should be able to simply use doc.getAs('text/html') and get the HTML content.  Instead, I have to forget about the doc object and use UrlFetchApp, OAuthServices, etc.

Comment: I guess it will be possible one day... but for now this workaround is the only way to get the HTML content of a document.

Comment: The "[originally suggested](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!searchin/apps-script/convert%2420html/apps-script/gjEVtRd-kIo/rrRPCq4hRAQJ)" link above doesn't work at this time.  `There is no group named "apps-script"` is the message returned by the browser.

Comment: Running this script today results in error Script is using OAuthConfig which has been shut down. Learn more at http://goo.gl/IwCSaV (line 25, file "Code").  I guess this no longer works.

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks for mentioning it here ;)